# Sonarscanner cannot reach sonarqube server using docker-compose

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I have just created my docker-compose file, trying to run sonarqube server along side posgres and sonarscanner. The sonarqube server and the database can connect however my sonarscanner cannot reach the sonarqube server.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:

    sonarqube:
        image: sonarqube
        build: .
        expose:
          - 9000

        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:9000:9000"

        networks:
          - sonarnet

        environment:
          - sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/sonar
          - sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
          - sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

        volumes:
          - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
          - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
          - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
          - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

    postgres:
        image: postgres
        build: .
        networks:
          - sonarnet
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"

        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar

        volumes:
          - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
          - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    sonarscanner:
      image: newtmitch/sonar-scanner
      networks:
        - sonarnet
      depends_on:
        - sonarqube
      volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src


networks:
  sonarnet:


volumes:
  sonarqube_conf:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

This is my sonar-project.propeties file:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=toh-token

# --- optional properties ---

#defaults to project key
#sonar.projectName=toh
# defaults to 'not provided'
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
#sonar.sources=$HOME/.solo/angular/toh
 
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

My sonar-project.properties is located in the same directory as the docker-compose file.

This is what happens whenever I start the services:

```
Attaching to sonarqube-postgres-1, sonarqube-sonarqube-1, sonarqube-sonarscanner-1
sonarqube-sonarqube-1     | Dropping Privileges
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 
sonarqube-postgres-1      | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 2022-06-12 20:59:39.522 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 2022-06-12 20:59:39.523 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 2022-06-12 20:59:39.523 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 2022-06-12 20:59:39.525 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 2022-06-12 20:59:39.533 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-06-12 20:57:58 UTC
sonarqube-postgres-1      | 2022-06-12 20:59:39.542 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: Project root configuration file: /usr/src/sonar-project.properties
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: SonarScanner 4.5.0.2216
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: Java 12-ea Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: Linux 5.10.117-1-MANJARO amd64
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
sonarqube-sonarqube-1     | 2022.06.12 20:59:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
sonarqube-sonarqube-1     | 2022.06.12 20:59:40 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:41087]
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | ERROR: SonarQube server [http://sonarqube:9000] can not be reached
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: Total time: 0.802s
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: Final Memory: 3M/20M
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:42)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.getScannerEngineFiles(JarDownloader.java:58)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:53)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:76)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     ... 7 more
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to sonarqube/172.30.0.2:9000
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:265)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:183)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:114)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     ... 10 more
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:130)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:263)
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  |     ... 31 more
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | ERROR: 
sonarqube-sonarscanner-1  | ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: It might be a timing issue where the scanner tries to connect before sonarqube is ready. After it fails, try running `docker-compose up -d` again.

Comment: @HansKilian That is what I was thinking as well, hence I had the `depends_on` key on the docker-compose file. I just tried what you mentioned but the outcome is still the same

Comment: `depends_on` only waits for the container to start. Some containers take a while from being started until they're ready to accept connections. Especially something like Sonarqube which runs multiple services inside the container.

Comment: Makes sense. I tried running `docker-compose logs` and `background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 33) exited with exit code 1` is one of the issues I came accross. I think the database shuts down before the sonarqube server can connect to it hence sonarscanner cannot connect to the sonarqube server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Hans Killian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) said, the issue was with the scanner trying to connect to the server before the server was up and running. I fixed it by just adding the following in the service of the scanner:
`command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 60 && sonar-scanner && -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/usr/src]`. This allows the scanner to be suspended until the server is up and running

I then added the following credentials in the `sonar.project.properties` file:

- `sonar.login=admin`
- `sonar.password=admin`